# Regex, getting a part of a string (Date + name)

Tags: regex

So my question is, how would i extract a name and 01.01.1960 (Only those 2 things) out of this text with regex?

basically how to ignore the ", Date: "

"name, Date: 01.01.1960"

Comment: What language are you using?

Comment: no specific language just the normal regex theory.

Comment: use parenthesis to capture some elements, use parenthesis starting with `?:` to not capture some elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`(.*)(?:Date\:\s*)(.*)`

Capturing group for everything until `Date:`

Non capturing on `Date:`

Capturing group for the remainder of the string.

Working example: https://regex101.com/r/MrNtWH/1